# Error setting Toolbar as ActionBar

Tags: android, eclipse, material-design, android-toolbar

I'm trying to replace the ActionBar of my app with a Toolbar but I can't because I can't use setSupportActionBar(). It says "setSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type MainActivity" even if MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity.
I don't know what to do, any help? Do you need me to post my code?

EDIT:
Now the code works but my app crashes on start and it says: "Attempt to invoke virtual method getTitle()". What do I miss?

EDIT2:
Everything works I forgot I had a Fragment and because of that it gave me nullPointer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without code, my only recommendation, is making sure your import statement is as follows:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Also make sure in your XML files that you are using

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

As your toolbar tag

Comment: The only thing I'm missing is import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; because I have import android.widget.Toolbar; If I try to add it, it says "The import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; cannot be resolved". I don't know why, I use the appcompat_v7 library.

Comment: @BlueMango do you find the solution of your problrm why it is not importing import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;?

Comment: @BlueMango. I am facing the same issue.. Could you please share how you did that?

Answer (score 7):

Now use :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

XML :

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Extends :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: This is actually the complete and definitive answer, because you show the extends AppCompatActivity.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

import this class instead of:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

or

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

The newer version requires the android class

Comment: The question was asked more than 6 years ago. It would be interesting to know if your suggestion using androidx works.